# Is it possible to turn off default hawtio plugins?

Tags: plugins, hawtio

I am using hawtio and i want to turn off some default plugins. if it is possible , please help me to fixe that. 
I tried to edit app.js as shown here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hawtio/vLhktYvHnCQ) but not very clear.

Comment: Can you mark this as answered as you can do this from hawtio 1.2.2 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming 1.2.2 release (we will do this release later later this month - eg January 2014), you can turn off plugins, and reorder the order in the navigation tab. You can do this from the preference.

There is a FAQ entry about this at: http://hawt.io/faq/index.html it also points you to the idea about creating a custom perspective where you can select which plugins to show/hide etc: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/hawtio-plugin-examples/custom-perspective

Comment: hawtio 1.2.2 has just been released.